# error when added choice field to content type

Tags: content-type, sharepoint-calendar, choice-field, custom-content-type

I have a custom content type, based on Event, for a Calendar list. 
When I add a Choice field to the content type, I get the following error whenever I try to Save a new item, or try to access the Edit page for newform.aspx:

[image]

Comment: maybe you need to configure regional settings (?). I heard that we used to query the ULS through powershell but it doesn't work anymore, so you might want to open a support ticket and have them lookup the correlation info, e.g. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/uls-logs-for-sharepoint-online/427976d3-b7f0-438b-a3bc-c7895a608c5d